# Implement bootstrap header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header, bootstrap-4

I have problems with implementing a bootstrap header in my code, but I think it's not my fault, but I dont know how to fix it.

The nav menu is always in phone view or something. I put my code in a `JSFiddle` so you guys can see my problem :

> Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/wx86vq2y/2/

and I got a screenshot like how it had to be: https://gyazo.com/aca2e255638350dc386812ea9878ecfe .
 Does somewhone know what is wrong? I cant solve this problem at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dize Design AOS-Header v.2</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Project</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

you can solve it by replacing the beta version bootstrap 4 css  to bootstrap 3 css [bootstrap3 url](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Please check the sample

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: How is replacing Bootstrap 4 with Bootstrap 3 a solution to a question on Bootstrap 4?